# meta name="viewport" content=width=device-width font size issue

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, web, viewport

I've made a website for mobile. When I use this tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

my website fits the screen perfectly on all mobiles. But then the font sizes look different especially on chrome mobile browser of android. Chrome changes the font sizes of the text and displays some parts bigger and some parts smaller. I used

```
body{
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
-moz-text-size-adjust:none;
-o-text-size-adjust:none;
-ms-text-size-adjust:none;
text-size-adjust:none;
}
```

but this doesn't solve the problem for some androids like Nexus. So I switched the viewport tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This sorted out the font size issue but this time some webpages don't fit all screen sizes perfectly. What shall I do so I get the best of two worlds? The paragraphs starting with "At Magenta Storage.." and "Give yourself more space.." are supposed to have the same font size.  [For the link to the website, you can click here](http://magentastorage.co.uk/mobile/storage-services.html)

Comment: Both of your meta snippets are exactly the same, what was the question?